# Wait until visibilityOfElementLocated() is not working in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I need to wait until some element will be displayed on page.
I have created method in which I have used `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated())`:

```java
public void waitForElementPresentBy(By locator) {
    try{
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    }catch (Exception e){
        Assert.fail("Element was not become visible");
    }
}
```

`wait` object was initialized in next way - I have set 300 seconds:

```java
wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 300);
```

But this method is not executed correctly. It does not wait until my element will be visible.

When I added `Thread.sleep(3000)`, it helped.
But how to waiting for element not adding `sleep()`?

Answer (score 1):

As per the API documentation [`visibilityOfElementLocated(locator)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

[*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) method is pretty much proven and a robust mechanism to wait for the ***visibility*** of a certain element. A bit unclear why you felt *...it does not wait until my element will be visible...*. A bit of more details would have helped us to understand the issue in a better way.

However, here visibility is considered with respect to *Selenium* but **not** to eyes of the user executing the tests.

**Note A**: If you are using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) you have to use the following WebDriverWait notation:

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(300));
```

**Note B**: As you are using WebDriverWait remember to remove *Implicit Wait* conpletely.

Comment: Maybe, I did not correctly understand the usage of  visibilityOfElementLocated(locator) .
My case : I need to login into app and checked that homepage is already opened (for executing further steps). Login process is executing slowly and need to wait 10-15 seconds before homepage is opened. I decided to wait for visibility of one element which is exist on homepage

Comment: Or such approach is not correct?

Comment: @tester Thats the correct approach.

Comment: So, maybe I need to increase amount of seconds for waiting? I have tried 300  and I thought that is enough. But it did not

Comment: 300 should have been more then enough. Checkout the answer update.